# How to align text and an image horizontally using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align text and an image next to one another but centered. I need an image on the right, and text on the left. Right now, I have both the text and the image in a figure container with an ID of 'title', then in my CSS code I have

```
figure#title { align: center }
```

I'm new to both css and programing in general, and I don't understand what other posts are saying, or what I should be doing.

Thanks

Comment: Please do not describe your code. Decribe the goal and the problem and paste the *actual* code.

Answer (score -1):

You should use inline elements (text in a span tag) and then use text-align center.

HTML

```
<figure id="title">
   <span> 
     Text goes here.
   </span>
   <img src="image path" />
</figure>
```

CSS

```
figure#title {
  text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cw7aky5v/4/